# How do i get my phone's IMEI number if it was stolen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, lost-phone, imei

My Samsung S5 mini was stolen and I now need the IMEI number. How do i get this without the phone?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get this information from your network provider as they will have a list of IMEI numbers that have been used by your sim card depending on the system that their customer care is using. They may need to contact a higher department in order to get this information for you.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have the packaging for the phone? The IMEI number should be printed on the packaging.

Alternatively if you used a Google account on your device, you can get it from accessing the [dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard) and going down to `Android`. Your IMEI should be displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

IMEI number is also available on the bottom of the box in which you have received you phone.

Answer (score -1):

Look on the original box of your phone. There you should find the IMEI number on a sticker. Good luck with finding your phone :-)

However you can also go to https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard and login with the account used on your phone and then go to 'Android'. There you will see all your Android devices and you IMEI numbers.

Comment: I dont see it on the box :/

Comment: It's on a price sticker.

Comment: Go to https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard and login with the account used on your phone and go to 'android' there you will see all your devices and you IMEI